# How to send object from detail view to another view in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views

I have a detail view that uses a Quiz object to display data stored in that object, like title and author. I want to have a button that links to a new page that displays different data from the same object. I don't know how to pass this data/object.

I can render the view and pass it the context of a specific quiz using an id but I want the id to change to be the id of the object from the initial page.

```
#assessement view
def assessment(request):
    context = {
        'quiz':Quiz.objects.get(id=1),
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz_app/assessment.html', context)

#detailview template for quiz
{% extends "quiz_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <article class="quiz-detail">
            <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
            <h2>{{ object.question_amount }} Questions</h2>
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'quiz-assessment' %}">Start Quiz</a>
        </article>
{% endblock content %}

#assessment template
{% extends "quiz_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Assessment</h2>
    <h2>Title is {{ quiz.title }}</h2>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: may we know which version of django you are using?

Comment: you have to pass the data as part of the URL. Make your `quiz-assessment` URL take a URL parameter taking the id of the quiz, and then fetch it in the view for the assessment page.

Comment: version is 2.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should make another view for url `quiz-assessment` and pass the quiz pk as you did above in your `assessment` view.

```
 def quiz_assessment(request,pk):
         quiz = Quiz.objects.get (pk=pk)
         return render (request,'assessment_template', {'quiz':quiz}
```

And in your url,pass the quiz id like this:

```
         path ('<int:pk>/quiz/assessment /',views.quiz_assessment,name='quiz_assessment')
```

And in your template you can give url like this:

```
        < a class="btn" href="{% url 'quiz_assessment' object.pk %}>
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments by @Robin Zigmond, you can do like this.

```
#assessement view
def assessment(request, qid):
    context = {
        'quiz':Quiz.objects.get(id=qid),
    }
    return render(request, 'quiz_app/assessment.html', context)
```

In the HTML file

```
#detailview template for quiz
{% extends "quiz_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <article class="quiz-detail">
            <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
            <h2>{{ object.question_amount }} Questions</h2>
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'quiz-assessment' qid=object.id %}">Start Quiz</a>
        </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

and in your urls.py change as:

```
path('quiz_asswssment/?P<int:qid>/', views.assessment, name="quiz_assessment")
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides, what SammyJ has suggested, You can use the django sessions library or the django cache framework. You can temporarily store the information you need for the next view and access it whenever you want to.

In what Sammy J had suggested, you will always to have make sure that the queryset is passed in the context, otherwise it will not be rendered.

```
def assesment(self, request, id):
    q = Quiz.objects.get(pk=id)
    request.session["someData"] = q.name
    request.session["qAmount] = q.amount
```

In your template file

```
<p>The title is : {{request.session.title}} and the amount is {{request.session.qamount}}
```

Note: Django sessions do not allow you to set a queryset as a session record, for that, you  can use Django Cache framework.

Example

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('quiz', q)
getting cache -> cache.get('quiz')
```

Sessions framework docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

Cache framework docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/